# Derivation of the exterior derivative?

Tags: differential-geometry, exterior-derivative

Given a (smooth) vector bundle $E\to M$ with connection $\nabla$ one can define the exterior derivative $d^\nabla:\Omega^k(M,E)\to\Omega^{k+1}(M,E)$ by $$d^\nabla\omega(X_0,\dots,X_k):=\sum_{i=0}^k(-1)^k\nabla_{X_i}\bigl(\omega(X_0,\dots,\widehat{X_i},\dots,X_k)\bigr)+\sum_{0\leq i<j\leq k}(-1)^{i+j}\omega([X_i,X_j],X_0,\dots,\widehat{X_i},\dots,\widehat{X_j},\dots,X_k)$$ for all vector fields $X_0,\dots,X_k\in\Gamma TM$, where $[X,Y]h=X(Yh)-Y(Xh)$ is the Lie bracket, and hats denote omission. However, to me this formula looks pretty random, not at all natural like many other things in differential geometry. My question now is whether there is some intuitive way to derive this formula?

For **example**, to define the derivative $f'$ of a function $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ I first start with a description (or set of axioms) of what $f'$ is supposed to do, i.e. "assign every $x\in\mathbb R$ the rate of change of $f$ at $x$", then notice that $f$ changes by $f(\tilde x)-f(x)$ over $[x,\tilde x]$, so a good approximation of its rate of change would be $\frac{f(\tilde x)-f(x)}{\tilde x-x}$, which becomes more accurate as $\tilde x$ goes to $x$, so I define $f'(x)=\lim_{\tilde x\to x}\frac{f(\tilde x)-f(x)}{\tilde x-x}$.

Is there a similar derivation of $d^\nabla$? One that starts with some (intuitive of rigorous) requirements that describe what $d^\nabla$ is supposed to do, and that arrives at the formula above?

Comment: The is the same formula that defines the usual exterior derivative on forms. I imagine you can also define it as the unique map satisfying some axioms or simply define it in local coordinates (which may be what you're looking for) just like the usual exterior derivative.

Comment: One way to motivate the definition of the exterior derivative of differential forms is through trying to generalize the fundamental theorem of calculus to integrals of forms on rectangular regions. Once you do that and understand that $d^2 = 0$ is equivalent to the fact that partials commute, then it becomes natural to define the exterior derivative $d_\nabla$ of vector bundle sections. Then $d^2_{\nabla}$ will no longer be zero but will be a zero-th order operator whose coefficients are components of the curvature tensor of the connection.

Comment: You two make good points. I know a proof for the uniqueness of the usual exterior derivative. Maybe I can adapt the three axioms (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_derivative#In_terms_of_axioms) to the generalized exterior derivative. Axioms 1. and 3. are easy to generalize, and with @Deane's comment I think that "$d^\nabla(d^\nabla f)(X,Y)=[\nabla_X,\nabla_Y]f-\nabla_{[X,Y]}f$ for all 0-forms $f$ and vector fields $X,Y$" might be an appropriate generalization of 2.

Comment: @Cubi73, sounds good to me.